# Неправильная работа скролла у контейнера и body(страницы сайта)

Tags: html, css, overflow, viewport

Всем привет! Я новичок в вебе и всё время сам находил решения, но сейчас не получается решить.

Все знают о проблеме вертикальной прокрутки страницы на смартфонах из-за адресной строки браузеров, которая скрывается/появляется во время скролла.

Если **блокам** указать строгие максимальные размеры **ширины 100vw** и **высоты 100dvh**, то они займут всю область экрана учитывая весь **интерфейс браузера** и начнут **динамически изменять высоту**, в зависимости от того, **скрыта** или **показана** адресная строка. В данном случае возникает проблема - **страница прыгает** при **скролле** из-за постоянного **подгона** высоты для блоков, что очень раздражает и мешает удобному использованию сайта. **Я решил найти обход** данной проблемы за счёт **объединения всех блоков в один общий контейнер**. Но, если:

1. **главному контейнеру** указать строгие размеры **ширины** и **высоты** в **100% от видимости вьюпорта**;
2. внутри **главного контейнера** добавить **два блока** по **100% ширины** и **100dvh высоты**;
3. **разрешить прокрутку**(overflow-y: auto) у **главного контейнера**, если контент не помещается в его размеры,

То, по логике, когда эти два блока **не помещаются** в главный контейнер, у него **появляется** вертикальная прокрутка, в таком случае **должен скроллиться** именно **главный контейнер**, а не сама страница. Соответственно, **адресная строка не должна реагировать** на прокрутку, и вот тогда мы получаем идеальное и быстрое решение данной проблемы в браузерах. **НО!** Я столкнулся с непонятным поведением скролла:

Вариант реально рабочий, однако он не работает, если главному контейнеру не указать какой то отступ(не важно, border для контейнера или padding для body). То есть, **если сделать всё так, как задумано выше**, то оно просто **не работает**, **всё равно** почему-то **скроллится** сама **страница браузера** и **адресная строка меняет своё состояние**. А вот если **главному контейнеру** допустим добавить **обводку**(border: 1px solid red), то тогда **данный способ** начинает **четко выполнять свою задачу**.

Какие действия я **предпринимал**, чтобы обойти и эту проблему:

- В html и body указывал по 0px ширины и высоты(и соответственно
  наоборот по 100vw и 100dvh);
- Указывал у них position: relative и z-index ниже, чем у главного контейнера,

Но это всё равно **не работало**.

Так вот, вопросы: почему такое странное поведение у скролла? Почему именно благодаря отступам/обводкам начинает всё работать? Хотя заметьте, что для всего указано box-sizing: border-box, но почему-то они всё равно влияют на поведение браузера. Также главный контейнер занимает все 100% ширины/высоты страницы, то есть перекрывает body. **Как это можно решить?** *P.s. решение с помощью математических вычислений(calc) и использования JavaScript не вариант, потому что решение точно должно быть на чистом CSS и более простым. Тут главное саму суть понять, почему так работает скролл и как избежать применения отступов.*

**UPD. Причину такого поведения я понял. Если у контейнера указать единицы измерения vw и dvh, то он начинает занимать всю область видимости экрана, и тогда происходит цепная реакция с самой страницей(с body), потому и скроллить начинает не контейнер, а саму страницу(адресная строка начинает реагировать на скролл и менять своё состояние). Но если добавить какой то отступ контейнеру(border например), то цепь разрывается и контейнер становится независимым от страницы(body), и тогда скроллится уже сам контейнер, а не страница(адресная строка перестает реагировать на скролл и изменять своё состояние). Сразу скажу, position: absolute или fixed, а также никакие z-index не помогают разорвать связь с body. А вот если для контейнера указать размеры в пикселях(подогнав под точный размер экрана смартфона), а не vw и dvh, то тогда всё работает и без border и скроллит контейнер, а не страницу. Помогите найти вариант как всё сделать без отступов, разорвав связь с body.**

Код прилагается, сами можете проверить, добавляя и убирая border.

**P.s. Запрещать прокрутку**(overflow: hidden) у **body** и **html** не вариант, потому что тогда **перестает работать перезагрузка** страницы на смартфонах с помощью **свайпа вниз**.

Лучшего всего используйте Яндекс браузер, чтобы быстрее понимать, реагирует ли адресная строка, или нет, потому что там оно сразу начинает работать, в отличии от Хрома например, где скрывается только если достаточное расстояние прокрутить.

Скриншот как работает данный код **БЕЗ обводки border** на смартфоне в Яндексе прилагается(там видно, что немного прикручено вниз и адресная строка спряталась). [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но если добавить border - то тогда не реагирует и адресная строка будет всегда видна(что нам и надо).

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F0F4FF;
}

.main-container {
    // border: 1px solid red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    min-width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    max-height: 100dvh;
    height: 100dvh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.block-1 {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    max-height: 100dvh;
    height: 100dvh;
}

.block-2 {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: green;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    max-height: 100dvh;
    height: 100dvh;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="block-1"></div>
        <div class="block-2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `А вот если главному контейнеру допустим добавить обводку(border: 1px solid red), то тогда данный способ начинает четко выполнять свою задачу.` дык добавьте, но скажем белого цвета на белом фоне :3 ну или transparent'ного цвета))) потом просто пометьте комментарием, что это нужный костыль, чтоб не удалить и все дела.

Comment: Я хотел так сделать, но у меня внутри этого главного контейнера находятся блоки с разными цветами, а transparent не будет работать, потому что блоки не являются родителем главного контейнера. transparent берет цвет только у родителя. Да и к тому же, это всё равно плохое решение(иметь какой то отступ, ибо задумка именно в полномасштабном использовании размеров вьюпорта), надо ведь всё равно найти единственный верный вариант, чтобы в будущем всем спокойно использовать.

Comment: вытащить контейнер из body и растянуть без указания габаритов, можно еще так `position: absolute; z-index: +1; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;` может и поможет...

Comment: Не поможет, я писал, что абсолютное позиционирование и изменение z-index не помогает)

Answer (score 0):

для телефона и проблемы выезжающей адресной строки

```
.my-element {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', vh + 'px')

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', vh + 'px')
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, это всё хорошо, но слишком уж костыльное решение( Я точно знаю что проблему можно решить без всяких математических вычислений и использования JavaScript, на чистом CSS. К вопросу добавлю данное уточнение